# sidewaysfigure does not work

Tags: floats, rotating, landscape

I am having trouble with 'sidewaysfigure'. It simply isn't recognized and says ' Missing number, treated as zero'

my code is

```
\begin{sidewaysfigure}[hbtp]
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0.01pt} % Chosen fairly arbitrarily
\centering 
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth-3cm,height=\paperheight-3cm]{cd4neutral.eps}
\caption{Variables in \textbf{CD4}-dataset}
\label{cd4neutral}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
```

and my preamble

```
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
%   \usepackage{chemarrow}
%   \usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{dsfont}
% indexing
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{float} % needs to be "fixed" by hyperref
\usepackage{placeins} % float placement, defines \FloatBarrier
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{txfonts}  
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{epsfig} 
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
```

does anyone see why this isn't working for me??

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: `sidewaysfigure` has no optional argument. However, create a _complete_ example document which shows the error. With your preamble and your example code it works for me.

Comment: Please always post a _complete_ (small) document that shows the problem. Your preamble shows some strange things but nothing that would generate an error. don't load epsfig (use graphicx) don't load lscape and pdflscape don't load setspace twice no ned to load amsfonts as you load amssymb

Comment: note that you might surprise yourself with `\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth-3cm,height=\paperheight-3cm]{whatever}` inside a `sidewaysfigure` environment; the width and height settings aren't changed inside a `sidewaysfigure`, so your settings should take account of the rotation: `\includegraphics[width=\paperheight-3cm,height=\paperwidth-3cm]{whatever}`

Comment: not relevant to the present question, but you've loaded both `amsfonts` and `amssymb`.  since `amssymb` loads `amsfonts` automatically, this is redundant.